# Animation nodes > Mesh Object Output > Use function

Tags: animation-nodes

The docs doesn't contain info about the use function:

[image]

Does anybode know what the function is?
When I enable this then my "Target" output object jumps to another place...

Thx!

Comment: Hello, if you don't enable it, the node doesn't serve any purpose. The target seems to jump elsewhere because your mesh is instantiated there. Hard to know for sure without more information about the rest of your tree

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Would you mind taking a look at my file please?
You'll see that if you enable the socket that the mesh is jumping to another location ;-(
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaC_--8KLG6Vm84NrmwfgCjCloOPNIG8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

That is socket `Enable/Disable` switch. When it is disabled data in the socket is not used. You need to enable that for writing data to target mesh. So that it always rewrites new data on the mesh.